# load keyed vectors in a gensim model

Tags: python, gensim

I have pretrained gensim keyed vectors in binary file downloaded from the internet, however i need to add more words to vocab and retrain the model, because sometimes it gives nonsense.
I understand that keyed vectors themselves can not be retrained, but model can. Is there any workaround that would load keyed vectors into the model? or can I pull out all the words and vectors and feed it to gensim model?

Comment: As long as you're doing some extra training to get vectors for words important to you, from text in your topical domain, why do you want to use someone else's pretrained word-vector model at all? Especially if that model sometimes "gives nonsense"  – as opposed to simply not having words you need.